# The right way to check if there are records in an ActiveRecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my views I've a code like this:

```
<% if @posts.any? %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>No posts found</p>
<% end %>
```

This generate in my console log:

```
...
Post Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `posts` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
...
Post Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
...
```

So this trigger 2 queries on my db. If I change the view in this way

```
<% unless @posts.blank? %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>No posts found</p>
<% end %>
```

only one query will be triggered:

```
...
Post Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
...
```

If I use `@posts.exists?` or `@posts.empty?` or `@posts.any?` I perform two queries, if I use `@posts.blank?` or `@posts.present?` I perform only one query.

So my question is: there are a sort of best practices to check if a collection is empty? When I should use `exists?`, `empty?`, `any?`, `present?` and `blank?` ?

Comment: Great question. Never thought of the conditions this way. Can you please also share what `present?` does? a single query or two like `any?` I would have checked but not with my PC right now.

Comment: `present?` works like `blank?`

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us correct logs? The first code loads data from `posts` when the second one uses `games`.

Comment: @MrShemek yeah... sorry in my local example I've Game class but change in this question to Post... fix edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exists? should be used as it is the fastest of all.

```
@post.blank? would retrieve all the post and count them.

!@post.present? would retrieve all the post and count them.

@post.empty? would retrieve the count of post.
```

blank?, present?, empty? is good to use if you have preloaded records.

```
@post.any? would be exactly the same as the previous option.
```

any? retrieves the records in the relation (unless they were preloaded), represents them as an array and then calls.where as exists? always queries the database and never relies on preloaded records and only one record is retrieved and that makes this method fast compared to any?

```
@post.exists? would retrieve the first post. That makes this approach fastest among those five.
```

Comment: I disagree because in the question example if I use `exists?` I perform 2 queries, instead if I use `present?` I perform only one query and so I think this is faster in a real app with a big db and many connected clients... let me know what you think...

Comment: @MrShemek also shows that exists? takes less time. And  If all we want to do is check if the scope returns any results from the database then exist? is better option. for present? we load all post  to check for presence. And exist? uses the count instead of loading the post and that too limeted to 1.

Answer (score 2):

After checking this (for preloaded records) I have the following results:

- generates additional query:

  - `exists?` (0.3ms)
  - `empty?`  (0.3ms)
  - `any?`    (0.4ms)
  - `present?`(0.5ms)
- does not generate additional query:

  - `blank?`

In the group of methods that generates an additional query, all of them except `present?` (`exists?`, `empty?`, `any?`, `present?`) generates the following query:

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM `posts` LIMIT 1
```

Only `present?` generates a different query (that is a little bit time-consuming):

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`
```

So, if you really want to reduce the number of queries, use `blank?`. In other cases, you can use any of the methods but I would suggest avoiding `present?`.

Comment: Im my case the `present?` method do not generate an additional query. I've double checked with a new rails 5.1.4 app.

Comment: I'm also using Rails 5.1.4. According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F), I would say that `.present?` should not generate an additional query (because it's `!blank?`) but my logs show something different.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, interesting (and perhaps unintuitive) approach which solves the double-query problem in your example is:

```
<% if @posts.each do |post| %>
  // do something with each post here
<% end.empty? %>
  <p>No posts found</p>
<% end %>
```

This takes the result of the `each`, which is the collection (loaded in memory, not retrieved again from the database) and checks whether it contains any records.